# get random 5 rows from each category where the main table and category table have one to many relation ship

Tags: php, mysql, join

Here is the situation i have two tables

```
of
    idof, (somtother data)
    ---------------------
    1, (somtother data)
    2, (somtother data)
    3, (somtother data)
```

and i have

```
ofc
    id, ofid, idcat
    ------------------
    1,1,1
    1,1,2
    1,2,1
    1,3,3
```

Here is what i use to get all from first table and joint it with second

```
SELECT * FROM `of` 
    LEFT JOIN (`ofc`) 
    ON ( `of`.`idof` = `ofc`.`ofid` )
```

Now i want to get 5 rows from of (imagine that second table has more rows) for each idcat, and i cant seem to get the sql right. i have done till now

```
select * from `of` as `f` 
    JOIN `ofc` as `fa` 
    ON `f`.`idof`=`fa`.`ofid`
where (
    select count(*) from `of` as `nf` 
    JOIN `ofc` as `nfa` 
    ON `nf`.`idof`=`nfa`.`ofid` 
    GROUP BY `nfa`.`idcat`
) <= 5;
```

Bit this subquery returns more than one row, and mysql complains. is there any other way to do this?without executing one query for each different idc?

Comment: Could you expand your data a bit, to show *real* column names, *real* data, and what you want the result of the join to look like?

Comment: the data is very simple the first table holds data for item offers(idof is the id of the offer), the second holds the category in which these offers fall into, one offer(idof) may be in more than one category(idcat).There is a third table that holds the names of the categories, but i don't need data from there, i just need to take 5 offers for each category with one query :), if you need smth else just ask. as long as for the data, the data here is actual :).